# Why "taufet" not "tauft"?

Tags: difference, grammar-identification

> Johannes lehret und taufet. (Matth.3,1-2 u. Mark.1,4-8 u. Luk.3,2-3)

Why *tauf**et*** and *lehr**et***, not *tauf**t*** and *lehr**t***?

Source: heading before [line 860](http://www.hieronymus.us.com/latinweb/Mediaevum/Heliand.htm#Koen)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The development of the German language has been characterised by a weakening of unstressed syllables (*Nebensilbenabschwächung*). Looking at the 3rd person singular present indicative, Old High German *suohhit⁠ – mahhot⁠ – saget* became *suochet – machet ⁠– saget*, with reduction of the vowel to Schwa. Later, the vowel was syncopated, yielding New High German *sucht⁠ – macht ⁠– sagt*.

The unsyncopated forms *suchet, machet, saget* were already outdated by the time Köne published his translation of the Old Saxon *Heliand* in 1855. Using these forms in the translation is a deliberate choice; it conveys the age of the original and makes the translation sound solemn. In the [comments](https://archive.org/details/heliandoderdasl00kngoog/page/n340/mode/2up) Köne uses the modern forms: *erscheint, bewahrt, zeigt*, etc.

Comment: It can also still be used today, as a creative / stylistic choice, or simply to fit a meter in a poem or song (IMO "sa-get" sounds better than "sa-hagt", for example).

Answer (score 14):

Same reason why it's "thou shalt not steal" and not "you shall not steal" in English. Just an archaic form of language that's still often used in religious texts.

Comment: Religious texts are not necessarily archaic, in most cases it was probably modern when they were written or translated. But in some cases the archaic may be intentional.

Comment: @RalfFriedl not updating them because "that's how they aways sounded" is more or less intentional and I think that was what he was getting at. David: perfect example with the thou, it really is the exact same idea/bundle of reasons